# Pandas Series.dt.week vs. pd.Period.strftime - what's the difference?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, week-number

When operating on a pandas series of dates, isolating the week number can be performed in two separate ways that produce different results.

Using the `.dt.week` accessor on a numpy.datetime64 value or a pd.Period within a series produces different results than using `pd.Period.strftime` on the same objects. The online documentation for [pd.Period.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html) states that all days before the first occurrence of the start week in the beginning of the year are counted as week 0. This follows standard python strftime behavior.

The `.dt.week` accessor seems to start at 1 and restart after 52 weeks, making the final two days of 2018 week 1 of 2019. The online documentation for [pd.Series.dt.week](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.week.html) only states that it returns the week ordinal of the year. This seems to be the iso week number?

Why is there this discrepancy in the behavior of the two methods? Which one should be used and why? How can I elegantly get the iso week number from a single python datetime (or pd.Period or pd.timestamp) object (as opposed to a series)?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date_string": ["2018-12-27", "2018-12-28","2018-12-29", "2018-12-30", "2018-12-31", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-07",]})
df2["Date_datestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date_string"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df2["Date_period"] = df2['Date_datestamp'].dt.to_period("D")
df2["Week1"] = df2['Date_period'].apply(lambda x: (x + timedelta(days=1)).week)
df2["Week2"] = df2['Date_period'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%U"))
df2
```

returns

```
   Date_string  Date_datestamp Date_period  Week1 Week2
0   2018-12-27     2018-12-27  2018-12-27     52    51
1   2018-12-28     2018-12-28  2018-12-28     52    51
2   2018-12-29     2018-12-29  2018-12-29     52    51
3   2018-12-30     2018-12-30  2018-12-30      1    52
4   2018-12-31     2018-12-31  2018-12-31      1    52
5   2019-01-01     2019-01-01  2019-01-01      1    00
6   2019-01-02     2019-01-02  2019-01-02      1    00
7   2019-01-03     2019-01-03  2019-01-03      1    00
8   2019-01-04     2019-01-04  2019-01-04      1    00
9   2019-01-05     2019-01-05  2019-01-05      1    00
10  2019-01-06     2019-01-06  2019-01-06      2    01
11  2019-01-07     2019-01-07  2019-01-07      2    01
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there was actually 53 weeks in 2018. I would recommend using a year-week combination, something like.

```py
df2['Year-Week'] = df2['Date_period'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%U'))
```

Edited:
To see the number of weeks, you can try

```py
df2["Week2"] = df2['Date_period'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%W"))
```

This shows 2018-12-31 as week 53.

- %U - gets the Week Number, using Sunday as First day of Week
- %W - gets the Week Number, using Monday as First day of Week

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't explain why there is a difference between the strftime method and the .week method, when to use which, or how to get the iso date week number (same to what is returned by the `.week` accessor) elegantly from a scalar value